# Is it possible to run four os's on a single laptop with 1TB HDD AND 8GB RAM

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation

I want to install Kali linux on my laptop which was preinstalled with *windows 8,windows 8.1,Ubuntu 13,04*.[image]

Windows 8 installed on  **dev/sda1**
Windows 8.1 installed on **dev/sda6**
Ubuntu 13.04 installed on **dev/sda8**
I want to install kali linux  on **dev/sda3** partition.Is that possible to install and boot all four os's?

Comment: yes it's possible. But I would prefer to use virtualbox or Vmware Workstation instead of installing 4 OS'es on my system.

Comment: If i install kali linux on /dev/sda3,then how i make kali to use the swap partition on /dev/sda9 or to create another seperate swap partition for kali linux?

Comment: i want to install kali linux on `dev/sda3` is that possible or not.If yes means,what i have to do for installing kali linux on `/de/sda3` and after that what i have to do to boot all the four os's.How did the linked question helps for me?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is definitely possible. During install, choose 'manual' installation. Choose the correct partition, and mark swap appropriately.